# EJS + htmlWebpackPlugin + ejs-compiled-loader. Can't make nav list using loop, getting TypeErrors

Tags: for-loop, webpack, ejs, html-webpack-plugin

My aim is to create navigation from data that I pass into `htmlWebpackPlugin` options, and I want to create it using `for` loop. Every time I try, I got errors like `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. Plus, I use `ejs-compiled-loader` because I need to use `<%- include path/to/template %>`. And I don't use `express` (and I would use it if only there is no other ways).

index.ejs:

```
<!-- index.ejs -->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
</head>
<body>

<%- include app/templates/header %>

</body>
</html>
```

header.ejs:

```
<!-- header.ejs -->
<div class="header">

  <div class="header-inner">

    <div class="header-logo"><img src="../../assets/images/logo.png" alt="Logo"></div>

    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <% for (var i = 0; i < htmlWebpackPlugin.options.navItems.length; i++) { %>

          <li><a href="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.navItems[i].href %>">
            <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.navItems[i].title %>
          </a></li>

        <% } %>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    // ...
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            IS_DEV: IS_DEV
        }),

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: '!!ejs-compiled-loader!./index.ejs',
            title: appHtmlTitle
        }),

        // HEADER
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.join(__dirname, 'app/templates/header.ejs'),
        //  template: '!!ejs-compiled-loader!./app/templates/header.ejs' tried as well
            navItems: [
              {
                href: './',
                title: 'startseite'
              },
              {
                href: './offers.html',
                title: 'angebote'
              },
              {
                href: './about.html',
                title: '&uuml;ber uns'
              },
              {
                href: './contact.html',
                title: 'kontakt'
              }
            ],
            test: 'Test'
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            // BABEL
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                options: {
                    compact: true
                }
            },

            // STYLES
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: IS_DEV
                        }
                    },
                ]
            },

            // CSS / SASS
            {
                test: /\.scss/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: IS_DEV
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: IS_DEV,
                            includePaths: [dirAssets]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },

            // IMAGES
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[path][name].[ext]'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

What am I doing wrong? If `ejs-compiled-loader` doesn't have access to passing params, what are the easy-maintaining alternatives? 
P.s. This is my first question asked here, please don't judge too strict. Thanks in advance.

Comment: AlexNaidovich, It would be much better to have the answer here be listed as authored by you. As I mentioned in my earlier comment, if you add an answer of your own with that code, I'm happy to delete the community wiki answer I just added. Please ping me if you do.

Answer (score 4):

The following is code which the question author, [Alex Naidovich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10155120/alex-naidovich), [edited into their question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/51594104/2) (everything below "SOLVED" in that revision) and indicated it resolved the problem. It's copyright 2018 Alex Naidovich and is under a CC BY-SA 4.0 license.

**nav.js:**

```js
module.exports = [
    {
        href: './',
        title: 'Home'
    }, {
        href: './about.html',
        title: 'About Us'
    }, {
        href: './contact.html',
        title: 'Contact Us'
    }
]
```

**webpack.config.js:**

```js
const NAV = require('path/to/nav.js'); // without extension

module.exports = {

    // ...

    plugins: {

        // ...

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: '!!ejs-compiled-loader!./index.ejs',
            filename: 'index.html',
            title: appHtmlTitle,

            NAV: NAV    // <- added NAV into plugin

        }),
    }

    // ...

};
```

**index.ejs:**

```html
<!doctype html>
<!-- html and head tags stuff -->
<body>

<% var NAV = htmlWebpackPlugin.options.NAV %> <!-- added this -->
<%- include app/templates/header %>

</body>
</html>
```

**header.ejs:**

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="header-inner">
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>

        <!-- header.ejs successfully gets variable NAV from index.ejs -->
        <% NAV.forEach(function(navItem) { %>

        <li>
          <a href="<%= navItem.href %>"> <%= navItem.title %> </a>
        </li>
        <% }) %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That should definitely work.

Comment: Nice. But what if I'm passing variables to ejs template in a express route (I render it and pass some dynamic variables)?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into something similar, and for my project it was due to using webpack 4. I had better luck with `compile-ejs-loader`.

I haven't gone as far as trying to pass in an object for the templates, all I needed was ejs include support.

Comment: I have solved this issue and it happened to be much easier that I've tried. if you are interested, I can show somehow.

Comment: yes, I'd be happy to hear how you solved it. thank you.

Comment: I've edited the question with the way to solve. If you are still interested in this, hope it helps :)